# VBA: Variable length array from user input (6 optional text boxes)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variables

I have a UserForm with 6 text-boxes, which the user can fill (or not) 2, 3, 4, or 6 or whatever he/she wants. These are called:

eb1, eb2, eb3, ...

At the end of the form there is also an 'accept' buttom, and when the user clicks it a text should appear as follows:

eb1, eb2, eb3, eb4...

Of course one of the problems is that if the user only fills 3 boxes, the result might be:

eb1, eb2, eb3, , ,

How can I do this? I guess I need something like a variable array and a for loop, but no idea how to do that, I am pretty new to VBA.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use a loop and an if statement to achieve what you want. Have a go at writing the code and then come back if you have specific issue / question.

Comment: Couldn't you just use ```eb1.Text & "," & eb2.Text & "," & eb3.Text``` etc.? Where exactly should the text appear? E.g. on the form or in message box?

Comment: You haven't specified exactly what you want the output to be when boxes are blank, so depending on that you could take Dee's suggestion and add If statements such as If len(eb1.txt) = 0 then ... either do nothing with that box, or add some of your own text to show user has left it blank

Answer (score -1):

Try below.
Create user form with 6 textboxes & name them as eb1, eb2, eb3, eb4, eb5 & eb6. Then add command button & paste below code to it. Then run the userform & enter some values to text boxes.
Click on the command button to see the msgbox.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
dim str as string
dim a as integer

'Check for text box name & loop through textboxes
for a=1 to 6 'No of text boxes have.(remember that your text boxes should have names like eb1
'find out if there is any blank textboxes & avoid them
if Controls("eb" & a).Value <> "" then
'Correction for front , if eb1 is empty
if str="" then
str=Controls("eb" & a).Value
else
str=str & " , " & Controls("eb" & a).Value
end if
end if
next
msgbox str
end Sub
```

Final messagebox will give you the result you want. (If I understood your question clearly). I have assumed that you don't need to show anything regards empty textboxes.

[Keashan](http://www.fiverr.com/keashan)